# Editing suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Is it possible / will it be possible to edit an edit after submitting it?

I ask this, because today I edited someone's post from my phone (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8820027). Because there is no preview function on the mobile page (which is a major drawback imho) I made a formatting mistake, which I noticed right after submitting the edit. Now I wanted to change that mistake, but there seems to be no way of correcting one self.

Comment: I am using Firefox on Android, and I didn't find any preview function. It's true, that I can use the desktop site, but still, I've seen a few other people commenting on how they hope their edit is rejected since they misunderstood the OP or something like that, so an ability to edit suggested edits might still be useful, no matter if there is a preview or not.

Comment: Ah, I see you have a separate question on that - I'll move the comment

Comment: *"a few other people commenting on how they hope their edit is rejected"* - perhaps that need would be better met with a *"withdraw"* option (i.e. allow the user to unanimously reject their own edit)? Then they can make a separate edit suggestion if they still think there's something they can add. Editing an edit when it may already have some approve/reject votes seems like a bad idea.

Comment: "Withdraw" seems to be a good option, I'd be quite in favour of that, as long as it doesn't count as a rejected edit.

Comment: The problem there would be potential for abuse - a user could withdraw their own edit to avoid a rejection if the review seems to be going against them. Perhaps it doesn't count as a rejected edit if there are no existing rejection votes, or if there are more accepts than rejects, but otherwise it does?

Comment: I don't like the suggested ability to withdraw edits from that is proposed in the comments.  For one thing all the work the suggested edit caused then just goes down the drain as anyone who reviewed the withdrawn suggestion has there review time wasted.

Comment: On the other hand, if the edit is withdrawn before it can be reviewed that means that less people have to review it, thus saving time and effort.

Answer (score 5):

You *can* modify your own pending suggested edits ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24490696#24490696)).
You can't suggest edits on posts that have pending suggested edits.

However, it's probably safer to wait for the suggestion to be reviewed, and should the problem still exist, to submit a new suggestion.

Comment: I see your point. What about withdrawing edits, so basically I noticed my mistake and want to withdraw the edit. That way I can fix my mistakes without getting a rejected edit or taking up precious edit review queue space.

Comment: This is incorrect, actually. You _can_ edit a suggested edit after it's been submitted. All you have to do is click 'edit' again. I should know- I've had to do this a couple of times myself.

Comment: @Kendra: Are you sure? I recall some kind of message telling me to wait untill the pending edit was accepted. It's been quite a while since my edits had to enter a review queue, though.

Comment: Positive. I just did so a couple of days ago. On [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8795865) yesterday actually. Originally, I had only edited the tags, then realized there were other problems with the post and edited them before it was approved.